# Can't see the table created with EF and code-first in Azure

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first

I've run the following lines to create a row in my DB.

```
Hazoo hazoo = new Hazoo { Name = "Ha Zoo" };
context.Hazoos.Add(hazoo);
context.SaveChanges();
```

The type is defined as follows.

```
[Table("Hazoos")]
public class Hazoo
{
  [Key]
  public int HazooId { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

I've got a single DB on my Azure account and when I run the following SQL

```
select * from Hazoos
```

I get a red message telling me: *invalid object name 'Hazoos'*. At first I thought there's some issue with connection or something like that. However, according to the log, the commands were executed properly and successfully.

So I thought - hey, let's see if we can retrieve said data - by this line.

```
List<Hazoo> hazoos = context.Hazoos.ToList<Hazoo>();
```

To my surprise, there it was! Three instances of Hazoo with the same name and subsequently raising index.

Where the duck (typo intended) is my data stored?! I'd like to list it using the Azure web client for managing my DB. I tried to check out what's in the DB by

```
select * from information_schema.tables
```

but according to that, there's no hazoos anywhere...

Comment: @ErikEJ I'm getting results of the manually created tables (both when staring with *use MyCoolDb* and without. Sadly, neither of the approaches gives me any hits on the table created by EF...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had this same issue and it was that my context base constructor parameter didn't match my connection string name in web.config.

I believe the tables were actually being created successfully on localdb.

```
public MyDbContext() : base("MyDbContext") {}

<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyDbContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=tcp:servername.domain.win.net,1433;Database=MyDb;User ID=appuser@servername;Password=password;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Could you also post the corresponding lines of config file, please? Was the constructor autogenerated but with incorrect parameter to the base? Or was it autogenerated with no call to the base at all?

Comment: I updated post with entire connection string (with sensitive information user/server names, passwords replaced).  My MyDbContext was entirely hand hand typed, not auto-generated. I just mistyped the base parameter and it didn't match the name of the connection string in web.config. Therefore EF was creating a default connection to localdb on my PC instead of hitting Azure.